# Updating Google Site with content from another page

Tags: python, google-apps, google-apps-script

Here is my situation: My company relies heavily on Google for email, calendar, docs, etc. Every department maintains a Google Site with department info on it, and I have recently been handed the task of maintaining my department's site. The company also has a lot of resources set up on a variety of intranet pages. I would like to include some content from our intranet pages on my Google site, and I can think of 2 possible ways to go about doing this.

Ideally, since it is just text I want to grab from the intranet page, I would like to write a Google app script to read the HTML from a site on my intranet and parse the HTML to extract the text that I want to have on the site. For testing, I just tried to display a page's HTML as text in my app like this:

```
function doGet(e) {
    var app = UiApp.createApplication();

    var myUrl = "http://www.yahoo.com";
    var responseHtml = UrlFetchApp.fetch(myUrl);
    var myLbl = app.createLabel(responseHtml.getContentText());

    var mypanel = app.createVerticalPanel();
    mypanel.add(myLbl);
    app.add(mypanel);

    return app;
}//END doGet
```

This works with public sites, but when I try it using the URL from an intranet page, I receive a "Syntax Error: DNS Error: ...". I assume because Google is hosting the site and does not have access to our intranet, although you cannot access any of our Google products from outside our network, so maybe this is not the case. I found one site that said to try using a UseIntranet parameter, but I still get the same error:

```
var responseHtml = UrlFetchApp.fetch(gemUrl, {useIntranet:true});
```

Am I doing something wrong here?

My second thought, since I only need it to update a couple times a day, was to write a Python script to run locally that will get the HTML from the intranet page and parse it, and then update the content on my Google site. I already have the local script to extract the content I need from the intranet, I would just need to find a way to update a Google site from a local python script. (I know this is a back-aswards way of accomplishing this, but if it works, its fine with me)

So is there a way to update a Google site from a local script?

Thanks in advance for any help!!

EDIT: 
 I should clarify where I am trying to do this from. I am using Google sites. When I go in to manage my Site, there is a section to add Google Apps Scripts. So I have created a Google Apps Script for my Google Site and that is where I am writing the code to try and read the HTML content of an intranet page. I then go in and edit a page on my site, select "Insert" and select "Apps Script Gadget". I then select the Apps Script Gadget I have created for my Google Site and add it to the page.

Comment: I'm rather confused by your question.  Are you using [Google App Engine](http://code.google.com/appengine/), [Google Sites](https://sites.google.com), or [Google Apps Script](http://code.google.com/googleapps/appsscript/)?  If you're trying to access data within your firewall, are you using [Google Secure Data Connector](http://code.google.com/securedataconnector/)?

Comment: I am using Google sites. When I go in to manage my Site, there is a section to add Google Apps Scripts. So I have created a Google Apps Script for my Google Site. I have not tried using Google Secure Data Connector, I will give that a look.

Comment: removed google-app-engine tag.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Two options:

1. The google apps script you wrote is being run by a Google server. You can use [Secure Data Connector](https://developers.google.com/secure-data-connector/) to give your script access to your "behind the firewall" intranet based data (this is where the "useIntranet" parameter comes in).
2. As you say you could also use a local script. That script would read your intranet data (as you say you have done) and then write it to the Google Sites page. You would use the Google Sites Data API and there's a [python library](http://code.google.com/apis/sites/docs/1.0/developers_guide_python.html) for that.

Comment: You were absolutely right on both. I ended up using SDC to create a rule to allow my Google site access to the intranet page. The Python API would have worked as well, but I would need to have full admin rights to my company's domain, which I do not.